# jQuery detecting class after it has been removed

Tags: jquery, locking

I'm trying to create a universal 'locked' class which would prevent user from interacting with any elements (anchors, buttons, etc.) while the block is loading. Nothing really fancy or secure, just simple loading lock.

I'm trying to detect click on elements who have class="locked" and deny the click with return false;. My problem is that even after the element has finished loading and I remove "locked" class, jQuery still detects that the element has it.

Code here:

HTML

```
<div id="block"></div>
```

CSS

```
#block {
background-color:#ccc;
width:300px;
height:100px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#block").addClass("locked");
$("#block").html("locked");

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#block").removeClass("locked");
    $("#block").html("unlocked !");
}, 4000);


$(".locked").click(function () {
    alert("locked! denying click event");
    return false;
});

});
```

You can see what is happening in jsFiddle: (open dev tools to see that the class has been removed after 4 seconds)

[jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cYKpQ/1/)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong (not recommend) ?

EDIT: Thank you for the useful answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your contents are `loaded dynamically` you can't access them `directly`.

At the load time i.e `DOM ready` dynamically loaded contents are not part of DOM.

So you have to use `event Delegation`.

```
$(document).on('click','.locked',function () {
    alert("locked! denying click event");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since '.locked' is dynamically added/removed delegate on the closest static parent element like this

```
$(document).on('click','.locked',function () {
    alert("locked! denying click event");
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cYKpQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this code:

```
$(".locked").click(function () {
    alert("locked! denying click event");
    return false;
});
```

you are adding that click event to any element which has the class locked AT THE TIME THAT CODE EXECUTES.  The click event is then bound to the element, and does not care whether the element still has class locked at the time the click occurs.

One way to fix is to unbind the click event when you remove class locked:

```
$("#block").removeClass("locked").unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `event.preventDefault()` method to cancel events. Try:

```
$(".locked").click(function () {
event.preventDefault();
    alert("locked! denying click event");
    });
```